# SQL Query: Join a table with existing multiple joined tables and get it's entries only if logged in user ID does not exist in the existing tables

Tags: sql, knex.js

My current code without joining table3 gets all id, name, employee_id from table1, and all id, kpi_id, score from table2 where kpi_id of table2 matches the id of table1 and deleted_at is null for all entries of table1 and table2. But table2 can have duplicate kpi_ids, in that case, I only get the entries with the maximum id number from table2.

Now, in addition to the above result what I want is to get all entries for every id of table1, if the employee_id matches this._loggedInUser.id, and if the this._loggedInUser.id doesn't match any employee_id from table1, then see if this._loggedInUser.id matches the contributor_id from table3 and if it matches then get all KPI information of the respective kpi_id from the table1 and table3.

Sample table1:

| id | name | employee_id | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | kpi1 | 5 | null |
| 2 | kpi2 | 5 | null |
| 3 | kpi3 | 9 | null |

Sample table2:

| id | kpi_id | score | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | null |
| 2 | 2 | 20 | null |
| 3 | 1 | 30 | null |

Sample table3:

| id | kpi_id | contributor_id | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 7 | null |
| 2 | 1 | 9 | null |

So far I've tried the following query:

```
const query = knex.select([
            't1.id as id',
            't1.name as name',
            't1.employee_id as employeeId',
            't2.kpi_id as kpiId',
            't2.score as userInputScore',
            't2.id as kpiScoreId',
            't3.contributor_id as contributorId'
        ]).from('table1 as t1')
            .joinRaw('left join (select t2.*, row_number() ' +
                'over (partition by t2.kpi_id order by t2.id desc) as seqnum from table2 t2) t2 ' +
                'on t2.kpi_id = k.id and t2.seqnum = 1'
            ).joinRaw('left join (select t3.*, row_number() ' +
                'over (partition by t3.kpi_id order by t3.id desc) as seqnum from contributors t3) t3 ' +
                'on t3.kpi_id = t1.id and t3.seqnum = 1'
            )

            const searchClause = {
            condition1: {
                't1.deleted_at': null,
                't3.deleted_at': null,
                't1.employee_id': this._loggedInUser.id,
            },
            condition2: {
                't1.deleted_at': null,
                't3.deleted_at': null,
                't3.contributor_id': this._loggedInUser.id,
            },
        }

            if (searchClause.condition1) {
            query.where(searchClause.condition1).orderBy('k.id')
        } else if (searchClause.condition2) {
            query.where(searchClause.condition2).orderBy('k.id')
        }

       return await query.then(kpi => kpi);
    }
```

Now, if I login as user 7 i.e. this._loggedInUser.id = 7, no result is generated even though 7 is a contributor_id in table3 for kpi_id = 1. The above query only works if the this._loggedInUser.id matches with table1's employee_id and if it doesn't match in table1 then it goes to table3 and in case of multiple contributors for a specific kpi_id, it only gets the one with the maximum id from the table3 which in this case belongs to contributor_id = 9 which doesn't match with this._loggedInUser.id = 7 so it's returning no result.

So, my desired output should look like this, if I log in as user ID = 7:

| t1.id | t2.id | kpi_id | score | employee_id | contributor_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 30 | 5 | 7 |